# Vue and Fullcalendar customizing day cell

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I need to add a button into every day cell. I know that I can do something similar to this:

```
dayCellContent: {
  html: `<button> button text </button>`,
},
```

But i don't really wanna do that and I would much rather use my button component. Also like this I would have to add the click listeners without Vue which I also don't like very much.

So is there a better way to do this? Preferably just pass in the Vue component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a component and initializing it using the Vue constructor like so.

```
const el = document.createElement("a");
 const calendarDayCellContentContainer = new Vue({
        el,
        render: (h) =>
          h(CalendarDayCellContent, {
            props: {
              buttonText: "whatever",
            },
          }),
      });
```

and passing the button.$el as DOM node.

```
domNodes: [button.$el],
```